# how can i remove the html content from the output?

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler

```
import urllib

data = urllib.urlopen("https://www.python.org/")
for line in data:
    line.strip()
    print line
```

I am trying to make a web crawler but when I run the above code ,some HTML stuff also gets printed .I only want the text portion of the web page and the hyperlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use beautiful soup library for making a web crawler and handling HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat rudimentary solution would be to .split over "<" and ">" tags and then just check the resulting list to remove elements starting at any "<" and ending at the next ">".